# Stripe charge after subscription, get metadata from subscription

Tags: python, django, stripe-payments

When I'm creating a subscription, I set some metadata to identify my order on the database.
When I receive the webhook `charge.succeeded`, the metadata from subscription, is not passed in this event and I can't identify the order related to this payment. How can I send the metadata on every webhook related to subscription.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The subscription's metadata live on the Subscription not the Charge object. A charge is associated with a specific invoice (if any) which itself is associated with a Subscription (if any).

It is simply not possible to set metadata on a subscription to see it ported over to the corresponding charge.

Instead, you would use the [API](https://stripe.com/docs/api#retrieve_charge) to retrieve the Charge and use the [Expand](https://stripe.com/docs/api#expanding_objects) feature to also fetch the associated invoice and subscription in one go.

In PHP it would look like this:

```
$charge = \Stripe\Charge::retrieve(
  array(
    "id" => "ch_1CP95G2eZvKYlo2C4pcS2pxm",
    "expand" => array("invoice.subscription")
  )
);
```

You can then access the subscription's metadata in your code directly.

Comment: What if someone wants to apply Radar rules based on metadata? When you create a Subscription you pay immediately (and that's something I want, because if the payment fails I do not want to have an invalid subscription around), however this means there is no time to update the charge afterwards to add metadata stuff.

Comment: @GACy20 that's not possible with Stripe's API today at least. You'd have to build your own logic based on other criteria unfortunately

Comment: Is there some other way (I mean: different from using metadata) to be able to distinguish *why* a payment was made? Basically my application may trigger payments for any number of reasons, I want to apply different Radar rules depending on the "type" of payment (type from my application point of view!). For example: accept prepaid cards only for one-off product purchases but not for recurring payments.

Comment: There are various rules that could apply here based on whether it's a recurring transaction, it's the first one or custom metadata: https://stripe.com/docs/radar/rules/reference

Comment: Ah, so finally I found that there is an `is_recurring` field... however it is not much use when dealing with Subscriptions with trials.. I want `Subscription::create(...)` to fail if the user tries to pay with a prepaid card even if the subscription has a free trial at the beginning, but radar rules only apply to the payments (right?) so it is not possible to tell Stripe "forbid the creationg of `Subscription`s that use prepaid cards" you can only deny the payments, not the creation of the subscription. What a shame.

Comment: Radar rules work with SetupIntents too if you enable the rule in your Dashboard settings at the bottom of this page: https://dashboard.stripe.com/settings/radar